# Android: Create Option Menu in single List

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, menu

I have 8 menu items. I am using `menu.add()` method to create all 8 menu items. Now when i run the app. The menu is shown in two rows with last item of second row being `more` and then clicking more a single list of the remaining 3 items is shown. I want all the 8 menu items to be shown in the single list without more button and rows. How can i achieve this functionality. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

**On Android 3.0 and higher, items from the options menu are presented by the action bar as a combination of on-screen action items and overflow options. Beginning with Android 3.0, the Menu button is deprecated (some devices don't have one), so you should migrate toward using the action bar to provide access to actions and other options.**

I suggest to use Action bar or Implement Sherlock library to have a vertical list of menu in your project.